# HTML, PHP and CSS related layout questions in IE/FF/Chrome

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

this is the temporary link to the website I'm currently setting up: http://bidonfollowers.com/index.php.later2

I have several questions concerning the layout of my website.

- In Firefox 26.0 however, the reCAPTCHA box is cut off to the right side and not below the message box.
- Also in Firefox, the Category text is in the upper part of the box (compare to how it looks in Chrome 32 and IE 11!)
- In IE 11 some of the text at the top area of the page is cut off.
- In Chrome you can see a link to "Privacy & Terms" with a blue font, which is not visible in the other browsers...

Please help me to fix these design flaws, every bit of help is appreciated!
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: please add code to your question. When your temporary code disappears your question and therefore all answers will not make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add clear: both to the style of div id="recaptcha_widget_div"

   ```
   <div id="recaptcha_widget_div" class=" recaptcha_nothad_incorrect_sol    
     recaptcha_isnot_showing_audio" style="clear: both;">
   ```
2. img tag of logo doesn't require closing tag. And add border=0 attribute.

   <img src="http://bidonfollowers.com/images/logo.png" title="" alt="" border=0 />
3. the easiest solution to avoid cutting off is to move your numbers beneath, edit paddings in style.css. It happends because of IE can't show semi-transparent png correctly.

   ```
   .third .pck3_cendetsh h2 { 
   font-size: 50px;
   padding: 10px 0px 0px;
   }
   ```
4. Link " Privacy & Terms" is visible in all of my browsers

Comment: 1. The problem is that the HTML code is generated by the PHP implementation of reCAPTCHA and my knowledge is limited. Please have a look at this: http://imgur.com/YOspoz0
When I edit the style type in the website it works, but how can I edit this code when I don't see it in my index.php?

2. I added the border=0 attribute but it didn't fix the text being cut off for me. Here is an example (Title and numbers: http://imgur.com/RIKYlQY)

3. Mysterious...

Comment: So, you can put your reCaptcha calling code into div: <div style="clear: both;">    ... reCaptcha ...    </div>

Comment: Okay, fixed the reCAPTCHA box with your help. Thanks! The problem with the cut off text is the text-shadow. Once I deactivate all the shadow options (for example for .third .pck3_cendetsh h2), the numbers are displayed correctly, but harder to read. Isn't there any solution where I can keep the shadows and the top of the characters? :P

Comment: Pls see #3 in my answer.

Comment: I tried to edit the paddings but all it does is move the text up or down, a part still gets cut off. Is that what you mean?